# marble probabilities

Tags: probability

A bucket has 3 marbles numbered 1, 2, and 3. Choose one and put it back along with another marble with the same number. Now choose a second and put it back along with a marble with the sum of your first two picks. Choose one more marble.

Find P(the first number was a 3 | third was a 3).

So what I did was draw out the entire tree of possibilities and then used the equation P(1st =3 AND 3rd =3)/P(3rd =3) and got 4/9 as the answer. Can anyone confirm this is correct? Also, is there an easier was to do this without drawing out the whole tree?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

Your task can be somewhat simplified if you notice that you really aren't concerned about any other possible third draws than $3$, so there's no need to go through a third stage of branching. That eliminates $24$ branches.

Another thing that can simplify the task is the observation that if your first marble was $3$, then *regardless* of what you draw second, there will be two $3$ marbles out of a total of five marbles when you make your third draw. That lets you immediately conclude that $$P(\text{first and third draws were }3)=\frac13\cdot\frac25=\frac2{15}.$$ Then you add those with the probabilities of the other six ways that $3$ will be your third draw, which you can calculate by using the tree.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid drawing the tree is counting the number of final leaves that would be in your tree. Format one triplet of draws as `abc` and denote an arbitrary draw by `_`:

`3_3` has $2 \times 4 = 8$ leaves, since the second draw is arbitrary and by the third draw there are two 3-marbles.

`x_3`, where the `x` is not a 3, has $2 \times 4 = 8$ leaves

`213` has 1 leaf on top of the one counted by the second case (since we have an extra 3)

`123` has 1 leaf by similar argument

Result: $$\frac{8}{8 + 8 + 1 + 1} = \frac{8}{18} = \frac{4}{9}$$